# PHP int to unique rgb color

Tags: php, colors, int, rgb

I have the numbers 1000 to 9999. I would like to have a function that gets an unique color in rgb for each number. The colors needs to be the same for each number every time the method is launched. Also the colors need to be very different when adding a number. So number 1 can be dark red, 2 light green, etc.

Hopefully some one knows how to do this! :)

This is what I got so far, but the colors are almost identical, thats not what I want!

```
for ($i = 1000; $i < 2099; $i++) {
  $rgb = getRGB(dechex($i));
  echo '<div style="width: 800px; height: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: ' . rgb2html($rgb['red'], $rgb['green'], $rgb['blue']) . ';"></div>';
}

function getRGB($psHexColorString) {
  $aColors = array();
  if ($psHexColorString{0} == '#') {
    $psHexColorString = substr($psHexColorString, 1);
  }
  $aColors['red'] = @hexdec($psHexColorString{0} . $psHexColorString{1});
  $aColors['green'] = @hexdec($psHexColorString{2} . $psHexColorString{3});
  $aColors['blue'] = @hexdec($psHexColorString{4} . $psHexColorString{5});
  return $aColors;
}

function rgb2html($r, $g = -1, $b = -1) {
  if (is_array($r) && sizeof($r) == 3)
    list($r, $g, $b) = $r;

  $r = intval($r);
  $g = intval($g);
  $b = intval($b);

  $r = dechex($r < 0 ? 0 : ($r > 255 ? 255 : $r));
  $g = dechex($g < 0 ? 0 : ($g > 255 ? 255 : $g));
  $b = dechex($b < 0 ? 0 : ($b > 255 ? 255 : $b));

  $color = (strlen($r) < 2 ? '0' : '') . $r;
  $color .= (strlen($g) < 2 ? '0' : '') . $g;
  $color .= (strlen($b) < 2 ? '0' : '') . $b;
  return '#' . $color;
}
```

Comment: RGB codes are actually 24-bit integers represented as hex, so it should be no problem. If fact it would be much easier if you could either expand of contract your range so that they are between 0 and `(2 ^ <a mutliple of 8>) - 1`, so `0 -> (2 ^ 8) - 1`, `0 -> (2 ^ 16) - 1` or `0 -> (2 ^ 24) - 1` - would it be possible for you to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the php function "dechex" to convert integer to Hexa RGB :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

In this page there is this function :

```
function toColor($n) {
    return("#".substr("000000".dechex($n),-6));
}
```

Not tested but can be help.

**EDIT after comment** : you can add some pseudo-randomiser in the function:

```
function toColor($n) {
    $n = crc32($n);
    $n &= 0xffffffff;
    return("#".substr("000000".dechex($n),-6));
}
```

Comment: This will also produce colors that are very similar - they will always be very blue and sometimes a bit green but never any red in the specified range.

Comment: Awesome! This seems to be what I was looking for. Akarun, are you sure there are no duplicate colors in the output?

Comment: Tested it. Seems like the are unique on my 1000 - 9999 scope. Great!

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to randomly pick 9000 colors, you can do it like this:

```
$color = substr(md5($number), 0, 6);
```

Comment: +1 That's not a bad idea at all. Slight collision risk but probably not enough to make it a serious problem.

Comment: +1 But it is `substr(md5($number), -6)`or `substr(md5($number), 0, 6)`